# How to get name of the called javascript function in firefox console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I was traversing the web page to get the flow of control in Firefox. So is there any way/command available for the console so that I can get the called function name. I don't want to edit my code base. I checked with "console.trace()" but that I need to put into my code. So if anyone know the way then please let me know. TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Firebug Profiler to know activity of javascript in firefox.

Firebug Profiler allows users to observe JavaScript activity and get statistics related to it.

This tutorial will help you to understand Profiler.

http://emtunc.org/blog/01/2013/profiling-javascript-execution-times-and-calls-using-firebug/

you can read here http://getfirebug.com/javascript  for more details about javascript debugging in firebug

Hope it will help